# Implementing Azure Mobile Services with OAuth and Not

Tags: azure, authentication, oauth, registration, azure-mobile-services

I'm trying to create a Azure Mobile Services Backend (JS) for an Android App and Website, with Windows and iOS versions down the road.

I see that you can add API keys to Facebook, Twitter, Microsoft and Google for users to authenticate via social accounts. I want my app to enable registration and login from these social accounts as well as have a standalone sign up form should they opt not to.

All data should be stored in a user table and I want to be able to store columns like phone number, and have users login and manipulate data specific to their account via Mobile Services APIs.

Could a knight or dame in shining armor point me to the right direction on how I can implement this? I haven't been able to find any articles that can help me create such a system.

Comment: I haven't found a tutorial for pure JS backend yet but I used the tutorial for the .NET backend successfully and it runs great. You can find how to authenticate users with the allowed providers for JS backed here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-android-get-started-users/. Then you can look into custom authentication for the .NET backend here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-dotnet-backend-get-started-custom-authentication/. It'll be a good place to start, but you have to convert it to JS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd start with this post by Chris Risner:

http://chrisrisner.com/Custom-Authentication-with-Azure-Mobile-Services-and-LensRocket

He links back to several earlier posts that should provide the background you need and also has some updates at the top to point you to changes since that post.

For profile information from the social providers I'd use these examples (and the associated links) from Carlos Figueira on how you can access more profile information from MS, Google, and Facebook.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2013/12/12/expanded-login-scopes-in-azure-mobile-services.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the reply - Custom Authentication is working great for me - except I still don't understand what changes I have to make in order to add user data from the social networks to the Accounts table. I need data such as the userId (e.g. "Facebook:123456789"), name, and email to be stored in the same table as the Custom "Accounts" table.

Comment: I'm using this post btw: http://chrisrisner.com/Authentication-with-Windows-Azure-Mobile-Services

Comment: Edited the original answer to include a link to information on getting details back from social providers.